# Does Java autobox when assigning an int to an Object?

Tags: java, object, autoboxing

Is this autoboxing?

```
Object ob = 8;
```

Will the above code first wrap the int literal 8 in an Integer and then assign its reference to variable ob? Because the java language specification has nothing on this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Will the above code first wrap the int literal 8 in an Integer and then assign its reference to variable ob?

Yes. (Or rather, it will box the `int` value into an `Integer` object, and then assign the reference to the variable `ob`. The fact that the integer value is a literal is irrelevant here, really. It could be a method call returning `int`, for example.)

> Because the java language specification has nothing on this case.

That's not true. I mean, it doesn't *explicitly* deal with assigning to `Object`, but it works the same way as normal conversions.

[Section 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) of the specification deals with boxing, which would convert `int` to `Integer`... and then assigning an `Integer` reference to an `Object` variable is a normal reference conversion.

Answer (score 7):

This specific case is detailed in the [assignment conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> Assignment conversion occurs when the value of an expression is assigned (§15.26) to a variable: the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable.
>   Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - [...]
> - a boxing conversion optionally followed by a widening reference conversion

So in your case:

```
8 (int) === boxing ===> 8 (Integer) ==== reference widening ===> 8 (Object)
```