# Does every data type inherit from Object?

Tags: java

I have a method that takes a parameter of type Object:

```
  public static void test(Object foo) 
    {
    System.out.println(foo);
  }
```

I can pass foo: Strings, integers, booleans, etc...pretty much anything. I think this is possible because Object is the base class from which everything else inherits from, and therefore it accepts any data type as valid. I could understand this being the case with objects like Strings, and Arrays. But why is this the case with primitive types? Do integer, char, and boolean also inherit from Object?

Comment: @Chopper - see [Handling Duplicate Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/) and signposts. Also, you should make the question in the title the same as the question in your body. The duplicate was for the question in your title. If you did not intend to ask the question in the title, then you should probably change it.

Comment: @Chopper - since you accepted an answer, we have a better idea of what you wanted to know. Here's another that might be more constructive to you: [Does Java autobox when assigning an int to an Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15139117/608639)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, primitive types **do not** inherit from `Object` since they're not classes. What happens when you pass a primitive type to this method from Java 5+ is called [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), and the compiler will convert your primitive into one of the wrapper classes. For example, an `int` will be automatically converted into an `Integer` (using temporary variables behind the scenes) which will make the code compilable.

Answer (score 1):

in this boxing then widening occurs ....for eg: if long then it First box in to Long then widen  to Object Class