# Why does this Number class assignment work (java)?

Tags: java, numbers, abstract-class, autoboxing

I looked for a duplicate of this but don't see a replica similar enough to satisfy.

You can't instantiate abstract classes in Java, and Number is abstract, so why does this line compile:

```
Number num = 3;
```

If it was Integer num, it would get autoboxed, but does autoboxing somehow work for Number too, even though it's abstract?  Or is something else happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not that auto-boxing works for `Number`. You are fully correct, the `Number` class is abstract and cannot be instantiated. Also no general mechanism for auto-boxing a primitive number into a `Number` object exists in Java.

It’s that auto-boxing works from `int` to `Integer`. The literal `3` is an `int` (with no exception). And `Integer` is a concrete subclass of `Number`, so putting a reference to an `Integer` into a variable declared as `Number` is trouble-free.

It may be a bit surprising that it works, I agree with you. The basic rule of auto-boxing is you can put an `int` where an `Integer` is expected, a `double` where a `Double` is expected, and so forth. We can hardly say that an `Integer` was necessarily expected on the right-hand side of your initialization. It seems they have extended the rule to be applicable here anyway. And it’s no doubt in the JLS somewhere (JLS: Java Language Specification).

Just for checking we may do:

```
    Number num = 3;
    System.out.println(num.getClass());
```

Output:

> class java.lang.Integer

You may extend the rule one step further:

```
    Object obj = 3;
```

It still gives you an `Integer` (not just an `Object` even though `Object` is a concrete class).

**Link:** Similar question: [Does Java autobox when assigning an int to an Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139117/does-java-autobox-when-assigning-an-int-to-an-object) (you will also find the references to JLS there)

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` is a subclass of `Number`, so `3` gets autoboxed from `int` to `Integer`, then the `Integer` gets stored in the `Number` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I suspected something like that was happening but needed confirmation. I picked the other answer because it elaborated a little more and both answers came about the same time, but I wanted to say thanks